# How to restore a live tile?

Tags: tiles, pin-to-start, icons

I accidentally deleted the music tile on the Start screen of my new MS Lumia 435 and haven't a clue how to get it back.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Swipe left when you are on Opening Screen,then you will get all the list.From here here you can press and hold on any app icon to pop up the menu regarding that App.
Here you will get multiple options like Pin to start,Rate and Review,Share and Uninstall.Select the Pin to start and you will get your app icon on the Opening Screen.